# Cinnamon Hotkeys for Favorites

Tags: linux, cinnamon, mate

I am coming from Gnome and trying Cinnamon. I can't see a way to bind `Super+0-9` hotkeys to the "Launch Favorites" panel.

Is this possible in Cinnamon, or Mate? I cannot determine where (if any) settings exist for this feature of if I need a special addon.

Thanks if anyone knows :)